# PHP if(isset($_COOKIE['visitor']) not working with page refreshs

Tags: php, if-statement, setcookie

I'm working on a simple cookie notice that appears on first visit only and again but only until 30 days has gone by.

The problem that I'm having is the page that is setting the cookie for the entire domain keeps receiving the notice once I go to a different page and then back again, unless I do a hard refresh (CTRL+F5) the notice just won't go away.

*In my header.php I have:*

```
$value = 'first_visit';
setcookie("visitor", $value);
setcookie("visitor", $value, time()+604800);
setcookie("visitor", $value, time()+604800, "/", ".example.com");

if(isset($_COOKIE['visitor']) && ($_COOKIE['visitor'] == true)){
  // do nothing
} else {
  echo '<div id="cookie">By continuing to use our Site, you are agreeing to the placement of cookies on your computer by us and our third party service providers.</div>';
}
```

So the idea of the code is that the user visits the site and then the page triggers a creation of a cookie, the value of this cookie is not important since the code will simply check to see if one exists, the first time the visitor visits the site, it does not exist therefore they it echo's else, going to other pages other than the page I just visited does `// nothing` as intended but if I go back to the page that triggered the creation, its still else, unless I do a hard page refresh.

*I have also tried:*

```
<?php
if(isset($_COOKIE['visitor']) && ($_COOKIE['visitor'] == true)){
  // DO NOTHING
} else {
  $value = 'first_visit';
  setcookie("visitor", $value, time()+604800, "/");
  echo '<div id="cookie">By continuing to use our Site, you are agreeing to the placement of cookies on your computer by us and our third party service providers</div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Sorry, it checks the cookie exists no? Since the value is first_visit but that's not checked.

Comment: why are you trying to set the cookie 3 times?

Comment: It's only loose comparison so the string will be true, issue is something else.

Comment: " Common Pitfalls:

    Cookies will not become visible until the next loading of a page that the cookie should be visible for. To test if a cookie was successfully set, check for the cookie on a next loading page before the cookie expires. Expire time is set via the expire parameter. A nice way to debug the existence of cookies is by simply calling print_r($_COOKIE);. " http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: @smith yep, that's why it works on the first visit but then after its stuck because its not rechecking. How do you do a recheck?

Comment: Can you use your browser's 'Inspect' function to view the cookes sent in both the request and response headers?

Comment: Cookies can only be set before any other output has been sent to the client, as they come in the response headers to the request. Is there any output on the page before this cookie is set? Does `setcookie` return true or false?

Comment: but thats a **new** cookie being created on every load

Comment: move `setcookie` inside the `else`. You need only one `setcookie` with cookie path "/" specified.

Comment: @MattClark setcookie is setting a cookie, I can view it in Inspect > Application > Cookies

Comment: @Deadooshka just tried that, same issue. I've added what you advised in my question.

Comment: "*if I go back to the page that triggered the creation, its still false*" isn't this just your local web history?

Comment: @James say page-a.php creates the cookie and I then click a href for page-b.php, I do not get the notice as expected, then If I click a href to go back to page-a.php I still get the notice, like its not even trying to read if I have a cookie present or not.

Comment: it sends `cache-control: max-age=2592000` and `expires: <date>` headers, so browser may use internal cache w/o http request.

Comment: @Deadooshka How can I force a recheck on the cookie? without reducing the cache-control since that's beneficial for resources and well, it's very possible that Cloudflare is causing the issue because I've used the code on other sites without Cloudflare no problem ;/

Comment: with `HttpOnly` flag it's not possible to get it thru the document.cookie on client side, so non-caching ajax request with random parameter may solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything wrong with your code - ie it's working as expected based on the code. I just don't think you see what the code is actually doing. You say the cookie is eventually set, but you are setting the cookie on a page, moving on, then using back button and getting to a page with that message again. This is likely browser cache, and likely confirmed as you say a hard refresh fixes this.

It seems odd the way you are doing all of this. All I can get from your question and code is you require:

- First visit - user sees message and cookie is set
- Consequent visits/pages after this - user doesn't see message because cookie is set

The only way you can avoid the browser back messing this up for you is to do a redirect after you set the cookie (eg `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`). but then you can't use the same file to show the message as by then the cookie will be set.

You should rethink this and handle the whole thing differently, but as it stands, with the code you have presented, all I can suggest setting a session.

header.php

```
session_start();

if (!isset($_COOKIE['visitor']) || ($_COOKIE['visitor'] != true)) {
    $value = 'first_visit';
    setcookie("visitor", $value, time() + 604800, "/", ".example.com");
    $SESSION['displayMessage'] = true;
} else {
    if (isset($SESSION['displayMessage'])) {
        unset($SESSION['displayMessage']);
    }
}

if (isset($SESSION['displayMessage'])) {
    echo '<div id="cookie">By continuing to use our Site, you are agreeing to the placement of cookies on your computer by us and our third party service providers.</div>';
}
```

On the first visit the cookie won't be set so it's set and a session is set, as the session is set it'll show the message. Then on any other page load as the cookie is set the ELSE will kick in and session is unset, and therefore the message is not shown.

(I reverted your cookie checks so you don't have that awful pointless `// do nothing` ;) )

The above code is very clunky, and I cried a bit writing it. Again, I advise you step back and rethink how you are handling all of this to make it more robust. Separate out your requirements into different files, better use functions, and then call things as and when you need them based on other things being set :)

Comment: Sadly, not using the back button. I'm clicking the logo which has href set to "/" and when navigating from page to page it does the same. Basiclly... If i set the cookie on the homepage, I can't get rid of the notice without doing CTRL+F5, now if I create the cookie on a different page, I get the problem on that page, but strangely enough on the homepage too...

Comment: I've just used your code, it works but occasionally I get it coming back. I mean If I spam click the menus going from page to page, sometimes it shows, sometimes it doesn't. Very odd.

Comment: works fine for me. suggest clearing all of your browser cache, history, etc. I'm using FF

Comment: Spaming the menus back and forth?

Comment: Very strange, It worked fine in FF then I deleted the cookie, now its not creating the cookie... GRRRRRR

Comment: Think I'll have another crack in the morning, thank you for your help.